# Whats app messages API not working online

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

[i have used whats app API messages costume API from this URL :](https://github.com/WHAnonymous/Chat-API) , its working in localhost mode but when i upload it to my website its not sending any messages to any number ,
 [i searched online for an answer and found this article talking about whatsapp threatens :](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/WhatsApp-threatens-legal-action-against-API-developers-1716912.html)
but am not really sure about it.
any help please thanks ...

Comment: Can you post your code that you've tried already, including any error messages/log entries you've received?

Comment: sorry but there is no error to show .. its only sending success 200 ajax request then nothing happen .. you can download the source from the url above and try it on your localhost .. you only need to set the target number and sender number and the password of the sender .. 
the way to get your account password :
http://www.17educations.com/whatsapp/how-to-get-whatsapp-id-and-password/

Comment: Please post your code here. Going to an external site (even github) will not encourage users here to try to assist you.